# Array initializer is not allowed here when passing as an argument to ArrayList

Tags: java

I have some `Model` classes that I am trying to declare a list with them but I get `Array initializer is not allowed here`. What would be a simple work around?

```
...
public class M1 extends Model {}
public class M2 extends Model {}

...
List<Model> mObj = new ArrayList<Model>({M1, M2}) //expression expected
...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In **Java 8** you could make use of the *Streams API*:

```
List<String> mObj = Stream.of("m1","m2","m3").collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Pre Java 8** simply use:

```
List<Model> mObj = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(m1, m2, m3));
```

For for information on this see:

- [Collectors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html)
- [Arrays.asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Arrays.asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) which will return `List<Model>` and then you can pass it to the constructor of [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)). **Note** if you assign directly `List` return by `Arrays.asList` to `List<Model>` then call to method like `add()` will throw `UnsupportedOperationException` because Arrays.asList return's `AbstractList`

You should change

```
List<Model> mObj = new ArrayList<Model>({M1, M2}) //expression expected
```

to

```
List<Model> mObj = new ArrayList<Model>(Arrays.asList(M1, M2));
```

because constructor of class `ArrayList` can take `Collection<? extends Model>`

Comment: @Bala, List<Model> mObj = new ArrayList<Model>(Arrays.asList(M1, M2)); should work. Do you receive any problem?

Comment: I get `expression expected`